# Simple activation script

Tags: php, mysql

The script is fully working, but I ask is there a better way I can do this rather than name all of the query variables, `$q`, `$q1` etc, and then use `if` `else` statements to execute the code.

```
<?php 
// open the mysql connection

require_once('mysqli.php');

// successful login variables

$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ? && password = ? && logcount != ''");
$q -> bind_param('ss', ($_POST['email']), ($_POST['password'])); 
$q -> execute();
$q -> store_result();

// wrong password variables

$q1 = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ? && password != ? && logcount != ''");
$q1 -> bind_param('ss', ($_POST['email']), ($_POST['password']));
$q1 -> execute();
$q1 -> store_result();  

// not active variables

$q2 = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ? && logcount = ''");
$q2 -> bind_param('s', ($_POST['email']));
$q2 -> execute();
$q2 -> store_result();  

// successful login query

if ($q -> num_rows == 1) {
    $q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE accounts SET logcount = logcount+1 WHERE email = ?");
    $q -> bind_param('s', ($_POST['email']));
    $q -> execute();
    $dbc -> close();
    header('location: shack');
    exit();
}

// wrong password query

elseif ($q1 -> num_rows == 1) {
    echo '<p>Your password is incorrect.</p>';
}

// not activated query

elseif ($q2 -> num_rows == 1) {
    echo '<p>Your account is not activated.</p>';
}

// blank email form entry

elseif (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    echo '<p>You did not fill in an email on the login form.</p>';
}

// account not found

else {
    echo '<p>An account could not be found.</p>';
}

// close the mysql connection

$dbc -> close();

?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Appears you are storing cleartext passwords and doing a 1:1 comparison.  **This is bad**.

You can clean the code up by doing the following and executing **1** query to MySQL:

```
require_once('mysqli.php');  
// successful login variables  
$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT email,dbClearTextPassword,accountActive FROM accounts WHERE email = ?"); 
$q -> bind_param('s', ($_POST['email']));  
$q -> execute(); 
$q -> store_result();

// check to see if you returned any information from your query
if ($q->num_rows == 0) { 
  // email doesn't exist in db .. #fail
  exit;
}

if ($q['accountActive'] != '1') { 
  // email account is not active .. #fail
  exit;
}

// check the password matches 
if ($_POST['clearTextPassword'] == $q['dbClearTextPassword']) { 
  // do some of your fancy code to process the successful login
} else { 
  // do some other fancy code to process a login failure
}

$dbc->close();
```

Comment: Ye I haven't got round to hashing the passwords yet, just still trying to get the cleanest code possible, I haven't seen this method yet, I will try implementing it and see what happens :) Thanks

Comment: will you donate 10% of your contract earnings to a non-profit organization that supports depressed coders if this answers your question?

Comment: Haha this is a non profit website, and it seems that I cannot just use simply $q['value'] as it returns an object error!

Comment: you need to spend more time reading about how to work with mysqli results.  my code was a quick example to show you the concepts of how to clean up your code ... answering your question.  it was not meant to be a production example.

Comment: @Basic 1982301 Programmers nodded in disappointment after reading that comment

Comment: @Basic: Try using $q->value, but as others mentioned read the documentation on mysqli and it will explain this.

Answer (score 1):

About efficiency: I suggest do not select data which do not needed.

For example, intead of

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ? && password = ? && logcount != ''
```

use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accounts WHERE email = ? && password = ? && logcount != ''
```

Also I fully agree with @sdolgy about not storing password as plain text.

Another point, not about efficiency, but about OOP design and readability: split code to few classes:

- All SQL queries go to DAO layer
- All checks move to service layer (which calls DAO-methods and throw exception when error occurs)
- All other actions leave as is

See also: [DAO pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object)